# Load Custom Default theme every time when user login into Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Want to set a custom theme to default theme every time the user login into the Fiori launchpad.

Using this t-code /UI2/NWBC_CFG_CUST , i have set the default theme and its working fine.

But when the the end-users selects the theme themselves via "User Preferences / Appearance from the launchpad"
   after that logout from the launchpad and again tries to login again this time default theme is not loading

its loading with the theme which is chosen from the ( user preference)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour as any customisation/personalisation happened at user level will get first priority , so If you have set the custom theme n user set another theme for themselves , that will take over on custom theme.